# How to transfer OS from failing hard disk to new external drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, external-hard-drive, operating-systems, transfer

I have an old Vista Laptop whose hard disk is failing. For various reasons I must have the same exact system back again.

I copied the entire OS on the C drive over to a new external drive and made it bootable using DriveImageXML (https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). I changed the BIOS to boot from the external drive and it seemed to work, however I'm sure the registry is full of paths that start with C: so even though it booted from the external drive (arbitrarily assigned volume F: by the system), I'm sure everything is still accessing files on the C: drive which is failing.

I tried renaming the C drive to some other volume name but Windows Disk Manager would not allow it.

What should I try now? Should I physically remove the old failing hard disk (C:) and force the system to access the external drive exclusively? But then what about all those registry paths looking for the Volume C: in their paths?

What is the best thing to do now?

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: Your easiest solution would have been to bit-by-bit clone the failing disk to a new disk of the same or greater capacity. Whatever mappings etc would remain because the data will simply have been mirrored and you could then simply swap the disks inside your PC.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, that is what I did.  Except I can't swap the drives because the failed one is an internal drive and the replacement drive is an external type over USB

Comment: If I physically remove the failed internal drive, will the system treat the new external drive as drive C:?  That would work if that is a possibility.  I guess my question is:  how I can make the external drive appear to be drive C:?  Thank you

Comment: No, it won't work the way you intend. A "clone" would be to replace the internal or for you to connect via USB to solely recover files- NOT try to boot from it.